# C/C++: Client never recovers a DTLS connection when server restarts

Tags: c, udp, dtls

i managed to create a secure connection with DTLS (using a PSK or a Certificate), my client is continuously sending requests every 3 seconds.
the code until now works fine, but, the moment i restart the server the connection is lost and won't reconnect, i checked the log file and the connection is stack in the client/server handhsake.

my question is, how can i make the client and server to re-establish the dtls connection every time its lost.

NOTE: when i use a normal UDP connection (No DTLS (without the psk or the certificate)) the connection with the server is re-established and i continue to receive data.

this here is the log file after restarting the server

```
May 26 09:42:21.079 DEBG created UDP  endpoint [::]:5683
May 26 09:42:21.079 DEBG created DTLS endpoint [::]:5684
May 26 09:42:21.079 DEBG created TCP  endpoint [::]:5683
May 26 09:42:21.079 DEBG created TLS  endpoint [::]:5684
May 26 09:42:24.992 DEBG ***[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:53057 (if1) DTLS: new incoming session
May 26 09:42:24.992 DEBG *  [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:53057 (if1) DTLS: received 271 bytes
May 26 09:42:24.993 DEBG *  [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:53057 (if1) DTLS: sent 60 bytes
May 26 09:42:29.995 DEBG ***[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:43399 (if1) DTLS: new incoming session
May 26 09:42:29.995 DEBG *  [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:43399 (if1) DTLS: received 271 bytes
May 26 09:42:29.995 DEBG *  [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:43399 (if1) DTLS: sent 60 bytes
May 26 09:42:34.998 DEBG ***[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:36123 (if1) DTLS: new incoming session
May 26 09:42:34.998 DEBG *  [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:36123 (if1) DTLS: received 271 bytes
May 26 09:42:34.998 DEBG *  [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:36123 (if1) DTLS: sent 60 bytes
May 26 09:42:39.999 DEBG ***[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:53973 (if1) DTLS: new incoming session
May 26 09:42:39.999 DEBG *  [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:53973 (if1) DTLS: received 271 bytes
May 26 09:42:39.999 DEBG *  [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5684 <-> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:53973 (if1) DTLS: sent 60 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

UDP (and so DTLS) tends to delegate some functions to the next layers. That enables the possibility of chosing a specific improved solution instead of a general one. E.g., if you use CoAP on the top of DTLS it's possible to detect that scenario, if you don't receive ACKs for CON messages even on several retransmissions. The client may then try to resume a dtls session or do a full handshake. But the trigger for that is from the upper layers.

Comment: thank you for the answer sir! yes i am using coap protocol with the libcoap library. 
and can u elaborate more on the part, about the client resuming the dtls session.

Comment: Which dtls implementation are you using?

Comment: am using openssl-1.1.1g

Comment: I failed to find, how libcoap is intended to trigger dtls to execute a new handshake. Maybe, you ask that project on your own, see "issues" on https://github.com/obgm/libcoap .